# How can I clear Chrome's 70GB cache?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, browser-cache

I noticed a sudden, precipitous drop in free space on my SSD.  I tracked this down to Google Chrome's `AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Cache` folder, which has somehow grown to ~70 gigs!

That seems unusual, but clearing a browser cache is no big deal, so I went through the usual route of "Clear browsing data", making sure to erase the cached images and files from the beginning of time.  However, this only reduced the size of the `Cache` folder by less than 100 megs.

How can I clear this (unreasonably?) large cache?  Is it safe to simply delete the folder contents?  How can I prevent my cache from growing to this size again?

Comment: What file(s) in that folder are using all the file space?

Comment: @Moab — thousands of 2 meg files with names like `f_02c65b`.

Comment: Did you try to manually delete them?

Comment: @Moab — I wasn't sure about the consequences of doing so, hence my asking.  :-)

Comment: Send then to the recycle bin, it mucks things up you can restore them, I doubt it will.